# How to manage internal links using short alternate URLs when the canonical URLs are complex to generate?

Tags: web-crawlers, canonical-url

I am working on an existing e-commerce website where **the canonical URL for product pages are long and complex to generate**, hyphenated, and ending by the product id: `https://example.com/brand-model-and-some-more-details-P1234`.

Some products have siblings that are displayed at the bottom of the product page as clickable thumbnails. **The siblings products** cannot be linked by their canonical URL as getting all necessary parameters to generate such URL would involve additional SQL queries and further script processing. Hence, they **are linked by a simplified URL** made of the product id:
`https://example.com/P1234`.

For this website, a URL is supposed to be canonical if at least one hyphen is present in the request URI.
Canonical and alternate `<links />` are generated on the fly for canonical pages, but cannot for the alternate ones. For the later ones, one could possibly mention that they are alternate, but the matching canonical URL is unknown.

```
  <?php
    if (!strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?')) {
      if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'-')) {
        echo '<link rel="canonical" href="https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" />';
        echo '<link rel="alternate" href="https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '-')+1).'" />';
      }
    }
  ?>
```

Additionally, **all canonical URL are mentioned in XML sitemaps**.

However, **search engines can still follow the alternate simplified URL** from the thumbnails gallery, and possibly select on their own a canonical URL different from the one that I chose.

After some reading, including documentation from Google, **I assume that I have to implement this**:

1. Add `rel=nofollow` to the simplified links of the thumbnails gallery:
   `<a rel="nofollow" href="https://example.com/P1234" >...</a>`
2. When the product page has no hyphens in the URL (i.e. simplified URL),
   add this to the page header: `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />`
3. Exclude all alternate URL from `robots.txt` using the `disallow` directive.
   The website lists over 1000 products, so that I would preferably use a regular expression.
   (This point is likely redundant with points 1 and 2, but for additional clarity.)

Would this be the right way to handle the duplicates?

I would appreciate some external perspective on the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Providing you have consistent canonical URLs, it shouldn't negatively impact you to leave off the nofollow and noindex flags.